# import txt file data into array while filtering characters Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I want to import data from a text file text.txt and import it into a array removing commas and \n. The files' data is similar to the following:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
3,5,2,7,6,5,5,2,6,1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
3,5,2,7,6,5,5,2,6,1
```

The code I have so far follows:

```
def ReadFile():
  myFile = open('text.txt','r')
  lines = myFile.readlines()
  print lines #print raw data

  lines[:] = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in lines]
  print lines #print lines after removing \n

  lines = lines.replace(",", "")
  print lines #print after removing commas

  lines = map(int, lines)
  print lines #print lines after converting to int
```

I cant remove the commas, and I cant convert to int. The error messages are as follow:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the `csv` stdlib functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this harder than necessary:

```
def ReadFile():
    array = []
    with open('textfiledata.txt', 'rt') as myFile:
        for line in myFile:
            array.append(map(int, line.split(',')))
    return array

print ReadFile()
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [ [int(item) for item in line.split(',')]
                            for line in f ]

>>> print read_file('text.txt')
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) you can do this:

```
# create a generator
def ReadFile():
   with open('text.txt','r') as myFile:
       for line in myFile:
           # send out the line just processed
           yield map(int, line.strip().split(','))

# cast the generator to a  list for printing
print list(ReadFile())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following, befor you do that with the comma and the int cast:

```
for i in lines:
     my_list.append(i)
```